# Can't box a struct that implements a trait as a trait object

Tags: rust, traits, box

I'm playing with Rust and here is the code:

```
pub trait TFilter {
    fn get_text(&self) -> &String;
}
...
pub struct ContentFilter {
    text: String,
    domains: String,
    body: String,
}

impl TFilter for ContentFilter {
    fn get_text(&self) -> &String {
        return &self.text
    }
}

impl ContentFilter {
    pub fn from_text(text: String, domains: String, body: String) -> Self {
        return ContentFilter {
            text,
            domains,
            body
        }
    }
}
...

fn filter_from_text(&mut self, text: String) -> &Box<dyn TFilter> {
...
&Box::new(ContentFilter::from_text(text, domains, body)) // is returned
...
}
```

I'm getting the error message:

> expected trait object `dyn filter::TFilter`, found struct `filter::ContentFilter`

> = note: expected reference `&std::boxed::Box<(dyn filter::TFilter + 'static)>`
> found reference `&std::boxed::Box<filter::ContentFilter>`

This is misleading as:

1. it does implements the trait
2. the compiler does know the size of `ContentFilter` struct

Any clue?

PS. The code is not good anyway (as it's unclear who owns the Box that is returned), but the message is misleading.

PPS. How a caching proxy can be implemented then:

```
pub trait TFilterBuilder {
    fn filter_from_text(&mut self, text: String) -> &Box<dyn TFilter>;
}
...
struct FilterCachingProxy {
    filter_builder: Box<dyn TFilterBuilder>,
    cache: Box<dyn TFilterCache>
}

impl FilterCachingProxy {
    fn new_for_builder(filter_builder: Box<dyn TFilterBuilder>, cache: Box<dyn TFilterCache>) -> Self {
        return FilterCachingProxy {
            filter_builder,
            cache
        }
    }
}

impl TFilterBuilder for FilterCachingProxy {
    fn filter_from_text(&mut self, text: String) -> &Box<dyn TFilter> {
        let boxed_filter = match self.cache.get(&text) {
            Some(found_boxed_filter) => found_boxed_filter,
            _ => {
                // delegate creation to wrapped TFilterBuilder impl (`filter_builder`)
                let boxed_filter = self.filter_builder.filter_from_text(text.clone());
                // ... and put to the cache
                self.cache.put(&text, &boxed_filter); // boxed_filter should be moved to make cache own it?
                &boxed_filter // looks strange: who owns it then?
            }
        };
        return boxed_filter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type should be just a `Box`, not a reference to a `Box`:

```
fn filter_from_text(&mut self, text: String) -> Box<dyn TFilter> {
    ...
    Box::new(ContentFilter::from_text(text, domains, body)) // is returned
}
```

([Minimal compiling version on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0f770607acef9e2c493dfeeb318c1d2e))

The box is newly created in your function, so you have to return ownership of the box. It's impossible to just return a reference to a temporary, since it will go out of scope at the end of the function.

A side effect of this change is that the unsized coercion from `Box<ContentFilter>` to `Box<dyn TFilter>` will now actually work. Coercions are only applied in *coercion site* like the return value. In your code, the type that needs to be coerced is nested in a reference, so no unsized coercion is performed by the compiler.

Comment: I've been thinking about it. However it's unclear how it will work with caching impl of the trait which actually uses `HashMap` inside: one can't return a new box referencing the same `Filter` trait obj. How would you implement the caching then (without copying)?

Comment: @4ntoine I'm not quite sure I understand you correctly, but it's correct that you can't convert a `&Box<Type>` to a `&Box<dyn Trait>` without storing the referee of the latter in a new place. `Box<Type>` is just a pointer, but `Box<dyn Trait>` is a fat pointer, so a reference to the former can't just be reinterpreted as a reference to the latter.

Comment: i've updated my question to show the code

Comment: What you _can_ do instead is return a `&dyn Trait`, which is a fat pointer pointing to the original concrete object.

Comment: so the `fn filter_from_text(&mut self, text: String) -> &Box<dyn TFilter>;` becomes `fn filter_from_text(&mut self, text: String) -> &dyn TFilter` ?

Comment: @4ntoine That should work if you have an owned instance of `ContentFilter` stored within `self` – you can return a `&dyn TFilter` trait object pointing to that instance. The code in your question doesn't seem to be that situation, though, but I can't really make sense of that code due to undefined identifieres like `TFilterCache`.

Comment: `TFilterCache` is just a cache trait with get/put/clean. How should it work if having a `HashMap` since it returns a reference and in order to return a Box it needs to be reboxed (a new Box created to a Filter instance) but the `filter` size is unknown as it's just a trait. I can rephrase: how to return something from a HashMap if it owns it and avoid copying?

Comment: @4ntoine Why would you want to turn it into a box? Just turn it into a `&dyn Trait`.

Comment: I guess at this point you should ask a new question with code representing your actual use case. Your example code doesn't contain any `HashMap`.

Comment: follow-up question with full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920550/the-proper-ownership-for-caching-proxy-in-rust